# Getting a variable from POST and redirect

Tags: php, post, joomla1.5

I managed to solve 90% of my problem from an earlier question, I'll ask it separately because the original one is overly complicated, while now I just need something I believe is really easy.

I have the following code:

```
// Make a MySQL Connection
$Db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$baseurl = JURI::base();
// Get a specific result from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jos_content WHERE pass='$value'") or die(mysql_error());  

// get the first (and hopefully only) entry from the result
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
// Print out the contents of each row into a table
```

and I can successfully get the "id" I need to create a link, if I manually provide the $value variable, like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $baseurl; ?>/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Test test!</a>
```

It works. Great.

Now, I need to be able to input the `$value` from a form. I've been using something similar, but I can't figure out how to set up the method and action of the form.

What I've been using in the past is:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['number'])){
    header('Location: http://www.yourdomain.tld/'.$_POST['number']);
    exit;
}
?>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="folder" id="folder" />
    <input type="submit" name="number" id="bt" value="Go To" />
</form>
```

Now, how do I modify the code above to take $value from the input and use it to redirect the user to a link constructed like the one I wrote above?

I know it's probably really easy, but I'm stuck.. Please, help! :)

--- Update ---

Ok, I think I'm getting close. My current code is:

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
$Db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$baseurl = JURI::base();
$value = $_POST;
// Get a specific result from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jos_content WHERE pass='$value'") or die(mysql_error());  
// get the first (and hopefully only) entry from the result
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
// Print out the contents of each row into a table 

if(isset($_POST['password'])){
    header('Location: http://myurl.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id='.$row['id']);
    exit;
}

?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    Password:  <input type="text" name="password" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit me!" />
</form>
```

but I'm getting redirected to my base url. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read up on SQL injection. You should NEVER pass an unsanitized parameter into a query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['number'])){
    header('Location: http://www.yourdomain.tld/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=' . $_POST['folder']);
    exit;
}
?>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="folder" id="folder" />
    <input type="submit" name="number" id="bt" value="Go To" />
</form>
```

Comment: That's the exact same script I've been using in another context for another similar thing, it's not gonna work like this. First I need to get the input and set it as $value so I can get the $row['id'] to redirect to... All you did was fixing the variable wording of the old script :) Did you actually read my post?

Comment: I think it's still not right, I also updated the code (check above), and I'm 99% there... It's 20 lines of code, it has to be something really tiny... that I can't seem to figure out.